# Regex clean up text where there's no text before/after a seperator

Tags: regex

I am trying to clean up some text where there are separators with no text before/after it.

The 'types' are

```
3150779 | 3674-4 |Water Supply Plan
3637730 |
 | 10903-155 | Layout 10903 DWG 155 29 M | 
| 10903-155 | | Water Supply |
```

I understand `[^\|]+` splits this but I want to get rid of the separator when there's no text before/after the separator. So the regex should result in

```
3150779 | 3674-4 | Water Supply Plan
3637730
10903-155 | Layout 10903 DWG 155 29 M
10903-155 | Water Supply
```

I would like to apply this in a google sheet where the cleaned text goes only into one column.

See https://regex101.com/r/GzbCEU/1

I have also tried `[\s]+\|\s(.*)` and this selects the separators but doesn't clean the text.

--- UPDATE ---
When I try the suggestion from Pushpesh Kumar Rajwanshi I get no value in GSheet...
[image]

and also same issue

[image]

Comment: Hey looks like there is a type in the regex you've used mine. In your sheet, I see you've written `$1` just before `(\|` and instead it is `$|`. Can you try and copy paste the exact regex I wrote in my answer? Use this `^ *(?:\| *)+| *(?:\| *)+$|(\| *){2,}` and write `$1` where you need to type replacement text.

Comment: @Sweeper you added a 2 step process that seemed to basically work but deleted it. Can you repost as I was just trying it and it seemed to do what's needed.

Comment: This will work with one step too, can you just try correcting the regex?

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi I tried that but get same result - I only made it $1 as I thought you wanted me to replace the $| with $1 for it to work in GSheets.

Comment: No the regex part remains as it is. You need to write `$1` where you need to write replacement text. I think there is some issue in writing the replacement text. Hope you are using the correct replacement way in google sheets.

Comment: And in case you are not able to make it using one replacement, [which should work as per documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/62754#regular_expression) given by you only, you can first use `^ *(\| *)+| *(\| *)+$` regex and replace with empty string and then use `(\| *){2,}` regex and replace it with `|`

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi sorry I don't understand the $1 use. Here's a quick test Google Sheet I did with this -can you see if you can edit it to work? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Rq0km6mjMp8NG91vStG6ghIZWMVNQ7YGOScEe6sxyE4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes, I just tried your sheet and it worked flawlessly. When you are doing find/replace, make sure you check the third checkbox that says `search using regular expressions`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190582/discussion-between-pushpesh-kumar-rajwanshi-and-georgec).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex,

```
^ *(?:\| *)+| *(?:\| *)+$|(\| *){2,}
```

**Explanation:**

There are three alternation parts for handling three cases.

- `^ *(?:\| *)+` - This one replaces all the `|` that are in the beginning optionally having spaces in middle of them
- `|` - Alternation
- `*(?:\| *)+$` - This one replaces all the `|` that are in the end optionally having spaces in middle of them
- `(\| *){2,}` - This one replaces all the `|` that are more than two optionally having spaces in between them but preserves the last spacing.

And replace it with `$1` that works in google sheets.

Notice the replacement with `$1` only happens when `|` are matched in third alternation group where it just retains one `|` out of multiple.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cye0x6/2)**

Edit: screenshots showing how to find/replace using regex,

Before replacement

[image]

After replacement

[image]

Comment: Seems good but what do you mean by replace with $1 - I tried =REGEXEXTRACT(AF2,"^ *(?:\| *)+| *(?:\| *)+$1|(\| *){2,}")

Comment: @GeorgeC: Replacement with `$1` means, whatever got captured in first grouping pattern which is `(\| *)`. So the way it works is, if any of the first and second alternation regex matches, then there is no first grouping pattern there so it gets replaced with empty string but if third alternation matches, then it replaces it with `|` and optional spaces present after that last `|` among more than two. I've tested it for many cases and it should work for all cases. [Check here](https://regex101.com/r/cye0x6/3) Let me know if you face issue in any of your samples.

Comment: OK but GSheets gives me an error when I try this. Will paste in to the question.

Comment: We finally worked out that I was expecting a regexextract function and the solution above is for a find and replace. Using the regex supplied here (https://regex101.com/r/cye0x6/4) we worked out that we could use the following to get the result I needed - '=IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(A2,"^ *(?:\| *)+| *(?:\| *)+$|(\| *){2,}",""),A2)'

Answer (score 1):

I think this re should work for you:
`/[ ]*(?<![\d][ \*])\| | \|$/gm`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GzbCEU/5)  (be sure to open the "Substitution" accordion at the bottom of the demo page to see output)

```
$re = '/[ ]*(?<![\d][ \*])\| | \|$/m';
$str = '3150779 | 3674-4 | Water Supply Plan
3637730 |
 | 10903-155 | Layout 10903 DWG 155 29 M | 
| 10903-155 | | Water Supply |';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

Output:

```
3150779 | 3674-4 | Water Supply Plan
3637730
10903-155 | Layout 10903 DWG 155 29 M
10903-155 |Water Supply
```

Comment: this seems to clean ex 3 and 4 but not example 2. Also how do I use this in Google Sheet? the options for RE are limited - https://support.google.com/docs/answer/62754#regular_expression

Comment: yes.  need to fix ex 2 and also spaces before "Water" in ex 1 and 4.  let me revisit.

Comment: re google sheet, looks like @Pushpesh has a solution and is working with you.  Post any tips and tricks here after completing the task.